# Authentication with AOP, Guice and the new RequestFactories

Tags: gwt, servlets, aop, guice

I would like to use the new RequestFactories and the new approach to do AOP with Guice to do the Authentication.

I would like to have for example a RequestFactory Request method in a JPA Entity for example

findCustomer(int id) which i can anotate for example with @NeedsAuthorization(rights=Rigths.ADMIN)

This is just an example, but i am not so experienced in this field and it would be nice if there is an nice tutorial which shows such a possibility. Maybe HttpSession based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Want to give myself an answer. After longer research i find a way to use Guice with RequestFactory in this software architecture example: https://github.com/mgenov/injecting-request-factory

In this project i saw an example of Authorizaton wit AOP: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/11587

In the dynatableRF example of GWT i saw how to do the Authorization on Request Factory level (with AuthFilter)